# Let $K/k$ be a separable field extension, $(A,m)$ an Artinian local $k$-algebra and $A'=A\otimes_kK$. Then $(A')_{mA'}$ is an Artinian local K-algebra

Tags: algebraic-geometry, ring-theory, commutative-algebra

I am reading a sequence of lecture notes written by Dorin Popescu on Neron Desingularization in dimension 1 (that can be found here http://hlombardi.free.fr/Popescu-Luminy2015.pdf) and came across the statement in the question in Lemma 3 on page 5. The precise statement is

Let $K/k$ be a separable field extension, $(A,m)$ an Artinian local $k$-algebra with $k=A/m$, and $A'=A\otimes_kK$. Then $(A')_{mA'}$ is an Artinian local $K$-algebra with maximal ideal $mA'$.

I am wondering why this statement holds? In particular, why $A'$ Artinian and why is $mA'$ the unique maximal ideal?

Any clarifications would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Artinian should be taken care of by finite dimensionality, but I'm not sure about locality - if one takes $k=\Bbb R$ and $K=A=\Bbb C$, then $A'\cong \mathbb{C}\times\mathbb{C}$ with $mA' = 0$, which doesn't make sense.